# How to create metrics of specific events in Google Analytics or Data Studio?

Tags: google-analytics, google-data-studio

On my site, I am firing an event when the user lands on a specific URL. I'm firing another event when the user clicks on a button on that specific page.

When I go to Analytics, I can see the Total Events + Unique events for each dimension (specific page view, button click on specific page).

How is it possible to create a new metric (I assume a calculated metric) to display the Unique Events as metrics for any dimension I'd like to use in a Table?

Here is an example of what I have now:

| Event Label | Total Events | Unique Events |
| --- | --- | --- |
| specific_page_views | 100 | 50 |
| specific_page_clicks | 20 | 10 |

...and what I'd like to achieve:

| Source | Specific Unique Page Views | Specific Unique Page Clicks | Specific Page CTR % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (direct) | 30 | 8 | 26.67 |
| google | 15 | 2 | 13.34 |
| bing | 5 | 0 | 0 |

I have been searching for an answer for many days now and can't seem to find the answer to this simple question. I will want to create multiple of these Metrics, not just 2.

Is this actually possible with Google Analytics or Google Data Studio? (I'm planning to use Google Data studio)